# Snapping to added guides in QGIS Layout does not actually align objects

Tags: qgis, layouts, qgis-print-layouts

I added some horizontal guides to QGIS layout with the idea of aligning my main map frame to the legend. I also activated the "Snap to Guides" option under View>Snap to Guides. When I snap the map frame with the legend, they are both snapped to the guide but appear not to be aligned: [image]

I am using QGIS 3.2.3. Why does this occur? If the guide is not supposed to align objects on the map layout then what on earth is its purpose?

Comment: Snapping to the guides seems to work fine in 3.6, but some of the alignment tools will behave unusually when the items have different reference points set in the `Position and Size` section of the item properties.

Comment: Did you snap the legend to the guide before adding the frame? If you add/edit an item's frame after it has been aligned, you'll have to re-align it.